# 3D Array with Java (testing example from "Java: The Complete Reference, 9th edition)

Tags: java, arrays, macos, java-3d, eclipse-luna

I was trying to reproduce a code from the book I am reading and can't get to make it work. Here is the code:

```
public class ThreeDArray {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int threeD [][][] = new int [3][4][5];
    int i, j, k;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            for (k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
                threeD [i][j][k] = i*j*k;
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                for (k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
                    System.out.print(threeD[i][j][k]+"  ");
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
}
```

I am getting this output:

```
0  0  0  0  0  
0  0  0  0  0  
0  0  0  0  0  
0  0  0  0  0  

0  0  0  0  0  
0  0  0  0  0  
0  0  0  0  0  
0  0  0  0  0  

0  0  0  0  0  
0  0  0  0  0  
0  0  0  0  0  
0  0  0  0  0
```

I am getting all zeros here and I can't find the mistake here. Please advise what is wrong here.

Comment: Okay, you've shown us what's not supposed to happen, but haven't told us what's supposed to happen instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong bracket placement: your second `for` loop should be outside the first:

```
int i, j, k;
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        for (k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
            System.out.printf("%d %d %d %d %n", i, j, k, i * j * k);
            threeD [i][j][k] = i*j*k;
        }
    }
} // move to here ...
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        for (k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
            System.out.print(threeD[i][j][k]+"  ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
// ... from here
```

With the way you had it you were incrementing `i` with your print loop, which meant your first loop of `i` exited on the second iteration. Now it prints:

```
0  0  0  0  0  
0  0  0  0  0  
0  0  0  0  0  
0  0  0  0  0  

0  0  0  0  0  
0  1  2  3  4  
0  2  4  6  8  
0  3  6  9  12  

0  0  0  0  0  
0  2  4  6  8  
0  4  8  12  16  
0  6  12  18  24
```

Comment: Thanks Andy! I can't believe I missed that.

Comment: @fthnm2014. For what it's worth, I would avoid declaring `int` for a loop outside the `for`. Put your bracket in the wrong place again, but remove the `int i, j, k` declarations and declare your `for` loops as `for (int ...)`. Your compiler would have probably thrown an error along the lines of `Duplicate local variable i` that you would have spotted it.